# Regex match two words or at least one

Tags: regex, perl

I have a problem with my regex string. I have two combinations of strings as follows,

```
2.3.8.2.2.1.2.3.4.12345 = WORDS: "String to capture"
2.3.8.2.2.1.2.3.4.12345 = ""
```

Regex:

```
1\.2\.3\.4\.(\d+) = WORDS: (?|"([^"]*)|([^:]*))
```

[https://regex101.com/r/kQ3wT5/10](https://regex101.com/r/kQ3wT5/8) - matching

https://regex101.com/r/kQ3wT5/9 - Not matching

This regex is matching only for the first string and not for the second where i have empty string. So the regex has to match on both scenario. And one more thing I really don't want to go with "global" match.

Comment: You need to [make `(?:WORDS: )?` optional](https://regex101.com/r/xl5VOT/1).

Comment: Are you showing all the possible strings you will encounter ? Then what is this supposed to match `[^:]*`. Btw, `(?|"([^"]*)|([^:]*))` will match _nothing_ if given the chance. And `i really dont want to go with "global" match` doesn't relate here unless you have a single string with all your data in it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much. Please put that in answer section so i can accept it.

Comment: @Raja: Posted. Please check.

Comment: @Raja: Glad it worked for you. If you find it helpful, please also consider upvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `WORDS:<space>`  optional by enclosing it with an *optional* non-capturing group:

```
1\.2\.3\.4\.(\d+) = (?:WORDS: )?(?|"([^"]*)|([^:]*))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xl5VOT/1).

The `(?:WORDS: )?` matches 1 or 0 sequences (due to the `?` quantifier) of `WORDS:` substring followed with a space.